# Bluetooth Low energy (BLE) library for Flutter app development

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have been using [FlutterBleLib](https://github.com/dotintent/FlutterBleLib) for sometime now, but this repo is not maintained anymore. So it is not suitable for production apps.
What other alternatives do we have?

**requirements**

- stable on android/iphones
- maintained with good community support
- open source and free for commercial use

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO as it's seeking software library recs. However, you can use [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble) which is being actively maintained and has the appropriate license.

Comment: you can use [flutter_ble_lib](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ble_lib) its stable and we are using since last two years

Comment: @NikunjRamani this is what I am using, they are not maintaining it or responding to any issues for years.

Comment: @Patola you can use flutter_blue_plus as i can see they are maintaining and gives regular updates

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) can be a good alternative.